# How can I populate html titles with a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a lightbox set up on my site with titles that look like this

```
<div class="Container" id="">
    <a href="Link" title="titleVar">Cool Picture</a>
    <a href="Link" title="titleVar">Cool Picture</a>
    <a href="Link" title="titleVar">Cool Picture</a>
</div>
```

and the list is going to keep growing. Is there a way I can have a second file where I keep all the titles and they get populated where the "titleVar" is? Right now what I am doing is putting the titles directly in there and the code is getting really messy because the titles get pretty long sometimes

Edit: To clarify when I say a "second file" I mean a separate html or xhtml list specifically designated for the titles. I remember seeing something similar once with a span tag

```
<span>title1
title2
title3
title4
title5</span>
```

and these were able to be populated. The problem is I can't find the file I did this with

Comment: from a file ? where would said file come from, what have you tried ? typically data is stored in a database you then would output your html via php or some other language

Comment: you would be better populating a database and then using a server side language to retrieve your data

Comment: would require either a server-side scripting or a JavaScript templating (such as [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/))

Comment: You *can*, via something like knockout, or just a JS file that includes the details and loops over the images - but you're adding code complexity, at least one additional network request, and extra rendering time (all things that matter to users of the site) -- just to keep the source code neater (which does *not* matter to your users).

Comment: `myObject["$(this).data('title')"]` is this what you want?

Comment: Definitely possible. One way is to use something like a JSON text file, or even a CSV file, that you pull in using AJAX to create an array of titles, then use a jquery each command to iterate through the anchor tags and populate them using the index of the each. However depending on the lightbox you're using you might need to be very careful about timings as the lightbox might need the titles there before it initiates in document ready.

Answer (score 2):

In your javascript you can set up an array with all of your titlevar's in it and then perform a loop through it adding them all to the container.

```
var titilevararray = ["title1", "title2"] //all your titlevars here

$.each(titlevararray, function(i, val){
    $("#Container").append('<a href="Link" title="'+val+'">Cool Picture</a>);
});
```

The code is only a guidance so tweak it to your needs.

Comment: This is the cleanest solution. You beat me to it. Having them in an array like that allows you to edit the array without disrupting the order of things, or you can intentionally reorder them very easily.

Answer (score 2):

You could setup a `.json` file and iterate through it to set the title:

JSON:

```
{
    titles: [
        { title : 'some title' },
        { title : 'some other title' }
    ]
}
```

Then run a `$.getJSON` and iterate the results:

```
$.getJSON("titles.json", function(data) {
    $(".Container").children("a").each(function(index) {
        $(this).attr("title", data.titles[index].title);
    });
});
```